# Making an Ajax Call with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have been trying to change the content of a `<div>` with a JQuery Ajax Call.
But nothing happens when I press the onclick `<a>` element.
This is my current code that I'm testing with:
Front.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
function testAjax()
{
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: 'Back.php',
     data: "id=", // Not using this yet >.<
     success: function(data) {
          $('#test').html(data);
     }
   });
}
</script>
</head>
<body><div id="test">HELLO</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="testAjax()">Change this</a></body>
</html>
```

and here is my Back.php:

```
<?php
echo "test";
?>
```

Nothing happens when I click on "Change this" however the content in `<div id="test">` should change to "test". Can someone help me with what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a typo,
I didn't know that the script with the jquery source had to be in its own tag >.<

Comment: This doesn't just apply to jQuery. All `<script>` elements should either contain JS between opening `<script>` and closing `</script>` tags or have a `src=` reference to an external file, but not both. By the way, if you wish to include an html tag as part of the text of your question/answer/comment you need to quote it with backticks: ` (I've edited this question for you, but keep it in mind for next time).

Answer (score 6):

You didn't close your first script tag and open a new one for your inline script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function testAjax()
{
    ...
```

Comment: Ahh that did it, you have my eternal gratitude, thank you Kevin B.

Answer (score -1):

You should apply `contentType: "html"` on it. May be that will help.